# How to publish a Windows-compatible executable from Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just finished my first C# console app on Visual Studio 2022 on Mac and I need to publish it to a standalone executable app. I am able to get the exe on Mac working fine. But my teacher needs to open it on Windows. How can I do that?
When publishing, VS on Mac does not ask for the target runtime machine at all...

Thanks.

Comment: Some potential solutions here? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129422/can-i-compile-net-c-code-on-my-mac

Comment: @Luke: That question is very old, and things have changed _a lot_ since.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can always publish for a different platform, e.g:

```
dotnet publish MyProject.csproj --runtime win-x64
```

This should give you a publish\win-x64 directory with a windows exe file in it. You can give that folder to your teacher.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply. I tried with this method. The warning I got was "warning NETSDK1179: One of '--self-contained' or '--no-self-contained' options are required when '--runtime' is used". It did give me a publish\win-x64 directory with lots of other files in it, but the directory was under "Debug" instead of "Release". Am I doing it right?

Comment: I've seen this warning as well - you can ignore it (the default is --no-self-contained). If you want a release build, add `--configuration Release` to the command line.